# Is there a way to generate the contents of 'securityDefinitions' as an object?

Tags: java, spring, swagger, swagger-codegen

I have the following snippet inside my swagger JSON:

```
"securityDefinitions": {
  "oauth2schema": {
    "type": "oauth2",
    "authorizationUrl": "http://localhost:9999/sso/login",
    "flow": "implicit",
    "scopes": {
      "write": "Allows writing".
    }
  }
}
```

Is there a way, using `swagger-codegen-maven-plugin`, to generate this into an object, and more specifically the scopes to be generated? I am using version `2.4.10` of the plugin.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "generating this into an object"? What object?

Comment: Any type of object. I just want to have this information generated in the target folder.

Answer (score 0):

You can use customized templates (CLI option `-t`) to create a `Security` class storing various attributes in the `securityDefinitions`.